# How to tell for sure if paint is eggshell or gloss?

Tags: painting, preparation

There is wood panneling in my bathroom on a cabinet and bath.  I can't tell if the old paint is eggshell or gloss?

Obv if its gloss i need to sand it before painting.  So how can I tell for sure?

Comment: even with eggshell, I would sand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a proactive approach and sand it in any case. This will lead to better paint adhesion which is a good thing. It is also a great idea to wash previously painted surfaces with a strong solution of TSP (tri sodium phosphate). Make sure to use good rubber gloves and hot water - for your protection and best results. The TSP wash does a fantastic jub of getting any gunk off the walls that can interfere with a good paint job. Especially in a bathroom there is always the possibility with soap film and over spray from foam cleaners on the walls and panelling. A strong TSP wash can also remove some of the gloss from a previously painted surface for some types of paint.

Answer (score 3):

[One paint company](http://www.roddapaint.com/product/paint-gloss-sheen.aspx) defines the various finishes as follows:

> - **Satin**: A finish with a low luster appearance. Washable surface, reflects some light.
> - **Semi-Gloss**: A finish that has noticable gloss and sheen. Washable, sometimes scrubbable surface, but shows surface
>     imperfections. Reflects light noticeably
> - **Eggshell / Low Gloss**: A finish ½ way between satin and semi-gloss with a noticeable gloss and sheen. Washable, sometimes
>     scrubbable, but may show surface imperfections. Reflects light
>     noticeably.
> - **Gloss**: A finish with a high degree of gloss and sheen. Scrubbable surface imperfections. Reflects light very well. If
>     properly applied almost gives the impression of ceramic or glass
>     finish.
>
> They also explain gloss and sheen:
>
> - **Gloss**: Measured at a 60° angle, it's the shininess or reflectiveness of a coating.
> - **Sheen**: Measured at an 85° angle, it's a moderately low degree of gloss that appears flat when viewed near or perpendicular, but
>     glossy when viewed from a low or sharp angle.

There is no industry standard for paint sheens, so one company's eggshell can be another company's satin, matte or low gloss.